# How to get first name of user using App_scoped_id in Graph Api 2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

Is there any way to find user first name using app_scoped_id in Facebook Graph Api 2.0
currently i tried this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/app_scoped_id
```

i can retrieve profile pic using app_scoped_id but not name or other details.
I use first name to show in leader-board and the username in leader-board is app_scoped_id i get after Facebook Login, well i can save name to in leader-board using separator like:

```
<app_scoped_id>:<name>
```

but people usually change there name, So is there any way to get name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the below end-point using the App or User access token, you can see information about the user, including name, gender etc:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{app-scoped-id}?access_token={app-access-token}
```

Which will return:

```
{
   "id": "{app-scoped-id}",
   "email": "email@domain.com",
   "first_name": "John",
   "gender": "male",
   "last_name": "Doe",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/{app-scoped-id}/",
   "locale": "en_US",
   "name": "John Doe"
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without access token because i can't store access token on server its change every time person log in to Facebook.

Comment: The App Access Token doesn't change, so use that.

Comment: @NirajShah Is this only possible for those users who have authenticated your app ?

Comment: Yes, the user needs to be authenticated. Facebook doesn't allow the use of real ids using Graph API v2.0 unless they haven't been authenticated.